How to automatically change theme from child component
I'm creating a Remix app where the user can choose between 3 modes (system, light, and dark mode).
When the user chooses a mode, it is saved in localStorage, but I would like the theme to change automatically at the same time (this is where it doesn't work).
root.tsx
import { MuiTheme } from "./components/MuiTheme/MuiTheme";

export function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        {children}
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MuiTheme>
      <Outlet />
      </MuiTheme>
    </>
  );
}

The component MuiTheme where the 2 themes (light and dark mode) are defined and where the saved preference to localStorage is recovered :
components/MuiTheme/MuiTheme.tsx
export function MuiTheme({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  // Light theme
  const lightTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: "light",
      primary: {
        main: '#40c463',
      },
    },
  });

  // Dark theme
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: "dark",
      primary: {
        main: '#3b49df',
      },
    },
  });

  const [themeAppearance, setThemeAppearance] = useState('system');

  useEffect(() => {
    const themeAppearance = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'system';

    switch (themeAppearance) {
      case 'system':
        if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
          setThemeAppearance('dark')
        } else {
          setThemeAppearance('light')
        }
        break;
      case 'light':
        setThemeAppearance('light');
        break;
      case 'dark':
        setThemeAppearance('dark');
        break;
    }
  }, [themeAppearance]);


  const selectedTheme = (themeAppearance === 'dark' ? darkTheme : lightTheme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={selectedTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

The last file account.tsx where the user can save the theme preference to localStorage:
routes/account.tsx
import {
  ToggleButton,
  ToggleButtonGroup,
  useTheme
} from "@mui/material";

export default function Account() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const [themeAppearance, setThemeAppearance] = useState('system');

  useEffect(() => {
    setThemeAppearance(localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'system')
  }, [setThemeAppearance]);

  const handleThemeAppearance= (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    newTheme: string | null,
  ) => {
    if (newTheme !== null) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
      setThemeAppearance(newTheme);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      orientation="vertical"
      value={themeAppearance}
      exclusive
      onChange={handleThemeAppearance}
      aria-label="Apparence"
    >
      <ToggleButton
        value="system"
        aria-label="System mode"
      >
        System
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton
        value="light"
        aria-label="Light mode"
      >
        Light
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton
        value="dark"
        aria-label="Dark mode"
      >
        Dark
      </ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  )
}

Saving the preference is done without problem, but is it not automatically updated when the user clicks on one of the 3 modes (ToggleButtonGroup/ToggleButton)?
How can I achieve this? I tried using useContext, but I can't do it.

LocalStorage is non-reactive, meaning, if you update the localStorage from one place in the app that it won't trigger other places reading from localStorage to update. You should update React state and persist the updated state to localStorage. You should also initialize the state from localStorage.
Move the theme state and change logic/handlers up into the MuiTheme component and expose the current theme and an updater handler. Create a React Context and provide the theme and theme updater to MuiTheme component's sub-ReactTree.
Example:
components/MuiTheme/MuiTheme.tsx
// Light theme
const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "light",
    primary: {
      main: '#40c463',
    },
  },
});

// Dark theme
const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: '#3b49df',
    },
  },
});

interface AppThemeContextProps {
  themeAppearance: string;
  setThemeAppearance: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
}

export const AppThemeContext = React.createContext<AppThemeContextProps>({
  themeAppearance: "system",
  setThemeAppearance: () => {},
});

export const useAppThemeProvider = () => React.useContext(AppThemeContext);

export function MuiTheme({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  // Lazy initialize from localStorage
  const [themeAppearance, setThemeAppearance] = useState<string>(
    () => localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'system'
  );

  // Persist theme state changes to localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeAppearance);
  }, [themeAppearance]);

  // Compute the derived theme object value
  const selectedTheme = React.useMemo(() => {
    switch (themeAppearance) {
      case 'system':
        return window.matchMedia?.('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
          ? darkTheme
          : lightTheme;

      case 'light':
        return lightTheme;

      case 'dark':
        return darkTheme;
    }
  }, [themeAppearance]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={selectedTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppThemeContext.Provider value={{ themeAppearance, setThemeAppearance }}>
        {children}
      </AppThemeContext.Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

routes/account.tsx
Access the current theme value and updater function.
import {
  ToggleButton,
  ToggleButtonGroup,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useAppThemeProvider } from "../components/MuiTheme/MuiTheme";

export default function Account() {
  const { themeAppearance, setThemeAppearance } = useAppThemeProvider();

  const handleThemeAppearance= (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>,
    newTheme: string | null,
  ) => {
    if (newTheme !== null) {
      setThemeAppearance(newTheme);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      orientation="vertical"
      value={themeAppearance}
      exclusive
      onChange={handleThemeAppearance}
      aria-label="Appearance"
    >
      <ToggleButton value="system" aria-label="System mode">
        System
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="light" aria-label="Light mode">
        Light
      </ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton value="dark" aria-label="Dark mode">
        Dark
      </ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
}




Theme
Example




System



Light



Dark




Window and localStorage unavailable in SSR
Instead of using a lazy initializer function for the useState hook you'll need to use a mounting useEffect hook to update the themeAppearance when the component mounts and is hydrated on the client-side.
Example:
export function MuiTheme({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  // Lazy initialize from localStorage
  const [themeAppearance, setThemeAppearance] = useState<string>('system');

  // Read from localStorage and set the state if there was a 
  // persisted theme value
  useEffect(() => {
    const persistedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (persistedTheme) {
      setThemeAppearance(persistedTheme);
    }
  }, []);

  // Persist theme state changes to localStorage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeAppearance);
  }, [themeAppearance]);

  ...


Thx @DrewReese! However, I have errors. void return "Parsing error: Expression expected.". Next, ThemeProvider theme return "Type 'Theme | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ components: Components;". At last ThemeProvider.Provider context return "Type '{ children: ReactNode; context: { themeAppearance: string; setThemeAppearance: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps". Could you help me again?

@arlioli03 Ah, just realized that ThemeProvider was already declared for Material-UI. I updated and renamed the context AppThemeContext to eliminate any naming collisions. I've tightened up the Typescript as well and added screenshots from a working Codesandbox. If you need more help let me know.

Wahou, thx a lot! I still have some errors :(( Firstly, ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined at /components/MuiTheme/MuiTheme.tsx (doesn't seem to generate any errors in the codesandbox) and secondly  => Type 'Theme | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ components: Components; (same error in codesandbox). Thank you agin for you help! I'm continue to read/understand your code :D

I have changed some code in order to automatically change the mode when the user select one of them. this part seems to be OK but I can't get the localStorage at the first load, I always have the error "LocalStorage is not defined". Maybe due to remix : https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/state-management?

const [selectedTheme,setSelectedTheme] = useState(lightTheme); useEffect(()=>{switch (themeAppearance){case 'system': if(window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {setSelectedTheme(darkTheme); break;} else {setSelectedTheme(lightTheme); break;} case 'light': setSelectedTheme(lightTheme); break; case 'dark': setSelectedTheme(darkTheme); break;} // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps},[setSelectedTheme, themeAppearance]); // Disabled to avoid "Maximum update depth exceeded" infinite loop when lightTheme & darkTheme are passed in dependencies

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/state-management - Local Storage : Server Rendering Limitation: The window and localStorage objects are not accessible during server-side rendering, so state must be initialized in the browser with an effect. - Is there a way to rewrite this code by using any effect ? const [themeAppearance,setThemeAppearance] = useState(() =>localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'system'); ? I've been working on it since yesterday morning and I can't do it (I'm a beginner in React and Remix). Thx

@arlioli03 I see, yeah, SSR would mess with reading window and localStorage sine they don't exist on the server. I've updated with a suggestion.

Hi @DrewReese, I updated my post to use cookies. I still tried to update my code with you suggestion but it's not working (localStorage is correctly set but the theme remains on system when I do a hot reload). In the console, themeAppearance value is "system" then "dark" but first value has maybe already been send to dom ? In any case, the theme remains on system... Thanks again for your help!

@arlioli03 Think you could create a running Codesandbox demo of your Remix app that reproduces the issue that we could try out and inspect live?
